# Who has a toiveling service in Los Angeles?

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping

What does a single girl do if she has a whole set of dishes (service for 12) to toivel and no time to do it herself?
I contacted Dish Dunking Service but he was unreliable and did not call back this morning as he said he would.
There must be more than one person toiveling large quantities of new keylim at least as a side job in Los Angeles, right?

Comment: @Linda For sake of clarification, do you mean single as in an individual girl or single as in not seeing anyone? If the former, then you must have a lot of dishes if you don't have enough time. In any case, I'd consider calling up some of the synagogues in the LA area and asking them about it. Maybe call a JCC and ask them as well.

Comment: Do you suspect that a single girl does something different than a single boy?

Answer (score 2):

Here in Saint Louis (Missouri), the girls' Jewish high schools impose on their students a community-service requirement (which, I should add in fairness to the students, they meet and exceed). One of the high schools' girls happen to advertise their services immersing dishes, and the same may possibly be true of a Jewish high school local to you. More likely relevant to you, though, is that whenever a local Jewish organization — or, sometimes, person — needs some light labor done free for a small project, it knows to call the high schools here: you might try the same with the Jewish high schools local to you.